# D3 + React Native - Data point value not updating when X position changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a custom line chart following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yh5AV9eNKk) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSucm5jjkRI) as well. Everything works fine, but when I drag my finger on the chart I want to show the value at the current position (line stocks app on iOS or Robinhood app). At first, it shows a value but its static and doesn't update.

**LineChart.js**

```
const d3 = {
  scale,
  shape,
}
const height = 300
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')
const verticalPadding = 30

export default function LineChart({ data = exampleData }) {
  const minX = minBy(data, el => moment(el.label, 'LT'))
  const maxX = maxBy(data, el => moment(el.label, 'LT'))
  const minY = minBy(data, el => el.value)
  const maxY = maxBy(data, el => el.value)
  const scaleX = scaleTime()
    .domain([moment(minX.label, 'LT'), moment(maxX.label, 'LT')])
    .range([0, width])
  const scaleY = scaleLinear()
    .domain([minY.value, maxY.value])
    .range([height - verticalPadding, verticalPadding])
  const line = d3.shape
    .line()
    .x(d => scaleX(moment(d.label, 'LT')))
    .y(d => scaleY(d.value))
    .curve(d3.shape.curveBasis)(data)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Svg {...{ width, height }}>
        <Path d={line} fill="transparent" stroke={GREEN} strokeWidth="2" />
      </Svg>
      <View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill, width }}>
        <Cursor d={line} scaleY={scaleY} scaleX={scaleX} data={data} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Cursor.js**

```
const { Value } = Animated
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default ({ d, scaleY, scaleX, data }) => {
  const translationX = new Value(0)
  const path = parsePath(d)
  const length = interpolate(translationX, {
    inputRange: [0, width],
    outputRange: [0, path.totalLength],
  })
  const { x, y } = getPointAtLength(path, length)
  const translateX = x
  const cursorX = sub(x, 4)
  const cursorY = sub(y, 4)
  const text = scaleY.invert(cursorX.__getValue())
  const onGestureEvent = event([
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        x: translationX,
      },
    },
  ])

  return (
    <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}>
      <Animated.View>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }], ...styles.label }}>
          <Animated.Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{text}</Animated.Text>
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.line, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]} />
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.cursor,
            { transform: [{ translateX: cursorX, translateY: cursorY }] },
          ]}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </PanGestureHandler>
  )
}
```

This is the result of the code above:

[image: current]

**Edit**
Here is the link to the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@clytras/intrigued-truffle

Comment: I can't see any usage of `scaleQuantile` (*like `const scaleLabel = scaleQuantile()...`*); the example uses it to make the actual text like `const label = scaleLabel(scaleY.invert(y));`. Also why are you doing `scaleY.invert(cursorX.__getValue())` instead of `scaleY.invert(cursorX)`? It would be very helpful if you can create an Expo Snack with this example.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a expo demo or something so that people can help you better

Comment: @ChristosLytras at first I was using `scaleQuantile` but it wasn't working for me so I decided to try something else. I am using `cursorX.__getValue()` because `sub()` returns a reanimated object. Sorry, maybe I should've added that in the post.

Comment: @ChristosLytras I created a working snack: https://snack.expo.io/@corasan/intrigued-truffle

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri https://snack.expo.io/@corasan/intrigued-truffle

Comment: @corasan no, your post should be like this because this is what you're trying to do with that way and maybe this it the culprit. Leave it as it is, I'll check the expo snack if I can find any issues.

Comment: @corasan please check my answer. I can create a github repo if you have trouble implementing my suggestions to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have use [React Native Reanimated](https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-reanimated/) [`call`](https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-reanimated/call.html) to get a callback on `translationX` value change and then inside this you can update the text, which it has to be using `setNativeProps` and since `<Text>` component doesn't have a `text` native prop, you'll have to use `<TextInput>` like in the [`revolut-chart`](https://snack.expo.io/@wcandillon/revolut-chart) example:

#### Cursor component code

```jsx
// Changed imports
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { event, interpolate, sub, useCode, call } from 'react-native-reanimated';

...

export default function Cursor({ d, scaleY, scaleX, data }) {
  // Create a ref for the TextInput component
  const textRef = useRef();

  const translationX = new Value(0)
  const path = parsePath(d)
  const length = interpolate(translationX, {
    inputRange: [0, width],
    outputRange: [0, path.totalLength],
  })
  const { x, y } = getPointAtLength(path, length)
  const translateX = x
  const cursorX = sub(x, 4)
  const cursorY = sub(y, 4)
  // const text = scaleY.invert(cursorX.__getValue())
  const onGestureEvent = event([
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        x: translationX,
      },
    },
  ]);

  // Update text value using xValue = 0 when the component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    updateText(0);
  }, []);

  // Create reanimated code to get a translationX change callback
  useCode(() => {
    return call([translationX], (value) => {
      // On translationX value change update the text using the value
      updateText(value);
    })
  }, [translationX]);

  // Function to update the text based on current translationX value
  function updateText(xValue) {
    const { x, y } = getPointAtLength(path, xValue);
    const cursorX = sub(x, 4)
    const updated = scaleY.invert(cursorX.__getValue());

    // Use setNativeProps to update the TextInput component text prop
    textRef.current.setNativeProps({ text: `${updated.toFixed(5)}` })
  }

  return (
    <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}>
      <Animated.View>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }], ...styles.label }}>
          <TextInput ref={textRef} style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.line, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]} />
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.cursor,
            { transform: [{ translateX: cursorX, translateY: cursorY }] },
          ]}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </PanGestureHandler>
  )
}
```

#### Example screen capture

[image: RN D3 chart]

You can check the updated Expo Snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@clytras/intrigued-truffle

Comment: I have another question. Do you know why is the cursor ahead or behind the pointer/finger? it seems to move ahead of the pointer in the middle of the graph, do you have any idea why?

Comment: That happens most likely because you're subtracting `cursorX` and `cursorY` by `4` (`const cursorX = sub(x, 4)`) and then you use these values to transform the `translationX` and `translationY` for the cursror `Animated.View` (`transform: [{ translateX: cursorX, translateY: cursorY }]`).

Comment: I'm not doing that for the line though, and it only seems to happen in the middle of the graph, right towards the end and the beginning the cursor and line seem to align with the pointer. Sorry, I'm new to d3 and svg so I'm a little lost haha.

Comment: I can see the issue is using the mapped value of `translateX`; if you change it to `transform: [{ translateX: translationX ...` it will work good for `X` but `Y` will get wrong!

Comment: yeah, you are right. The cursor doesn't stay on the line path if I change it to `translationX`. I will have to figure out a way for it to follow the line path and the pointer hmmm.

Comment: I believe the issue is with the `length = interpolate(translationX, ...`. If you look carefully, you'll notice that the distance between the cursor and the touch grows as it goes towards to the center and it gets back to normal when it goes near start `0` or near end `width`.

Comment: inside the `updateText` function, when I console log `y.__getValue()` I noticed that towards the end (right) the numbers are low, in the middle are high, and towards the beginning (left) the numbers start to decrease again, is that normal?